# What is the name of component handling the HTTP requests from client in more complex infrastractures that just "client-server"?

Tags: architecture, web-applications

Although the splitting of web application/ web sites to front-end (client) and back-end (server) is popular, this binary division is frequently pretty far from actual complexity of architecture:

- The database could be in separate server
- Except client, "server" (already ambiguous term) and dababase, there are could be some third-party services, e. g. logging or analytics.
- There are could be multiple databases

What I want to know in this question is what the name of component X in below scheme?

[image]

- It is definitely not "server" anymore because database has own server and third-party services has own servers. Ever it is the "server" anyway, we need to distinguish it with other servers which presents in architecture.  (When "serverless API" being spoken, it means that server is belong to by third-party service)
- If it is the "backend", is it O'K to not include the DataBase to it? Is it in separate server or not, it is the "backend" in relation to "frontend".

I had to want to call it "servlet", but I afraid that Java engineers had put other meaning to it...

Comment: What about "HTTP server"? Anyway, you just have to name it in a way you can distinguish it from other components in the context of your *real* system.

Comment: It's certainly a server from the perspective of your client. Calling it a “server” or “backend” is probably entirely appropriate. HTTP servers that forward requests (with minimal modification) to other servers are also a *reverse proxy*. Such proxies are often used to terminate TLS connections.  If a service just aggregates APIs from other services, it is also a *API gateway*. Such gateways contain little business logic, typically at most authentication.

Answer (score 2):

What you are drawing is still a client/server architecture: there is a client (usually many) connecting to a server (usually one) for being served. All details of how the server is designed is completely hidden from the client; this is a basic feature of a client/server model.

What you are actually should be asking is: what are possible architectures of servers?

I think you are also confusing terms here i.e. by using „server“ as role (the connection point for clients), „server“ as the complete infrastructure required to serve a request by a client, and „server“ as a common name for a component within the server architecture (database server)